# What is the most suitable data type (differences or considerations) in Java for mapping time and timestamp with time zone from PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, postgresql

I'm developing an Spring Boot 3.1.5 (Java 17) based app which uses a PostgreSQL database, the app is intended to help employees with their attendance record.

which is a good Java data type to map:

- Time **with** time zone
- Timestamp **with** time zone

Also, is it a good practice to use time zone data types for records ?

At first I've created DDL and use spring's `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate` in application.properties and that works ok.

But if I use `create`, and see the tables in PgAdmin the resulting data types are time/timestamp **without** zone

Comment: Err, `java.sql.Date` and `javax.sql.Timestamp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably will store it without time zone or more precisely I would convert all input dates into UTC. So after u can convert it into any timezone.

For example one of the users first log in in UTC+1 but tomorrow change location to UTC+2. It will be easier to convert all the date afterwards.

Use time package, like LocalDateTime as a data type. Like this

```java
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
ZonedDateTime nowUTC = now.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
save(nowUTC.toLocalDateTime());
```

Or simple use Instant class.

```java
var instant = Instant.now();//get current timestamp
var zone = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC+1"));//convert to any timezone
```

Comment: Basically what you have said is you should really store as `timestamptz` as that type does just that, stores the values at UTC.

Comment: Sure. But I would suggest to use Instant from java.time package rather than Timestamp class.